# pass list to child template cloud formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

im creating a nested cf templates and i have parent template which has this list parameter

```
 "DatabaseSubnets": {
      "Description": "The subnets to place database instances in.",
      "Type": "List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>"
    }
```

and resources like this

```
"Resources": {
    "VPCStack": {
      "Type": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
      "Properties": {
        "Parameters": {
                    "ClassB": {                      

                           "Ref": "ClassB"                     

                    }                
                },
          "TemplateURL": "https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/xxx/vpc-2.json",
          "TimeoutInMinutes": "5"
      }
    },
      "RDSStack": {
      "Type": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
      "Properties": {
        "Parameters": {
                   "DatabaseInstanceType":{"Ref":"DatabaseInstanceType"},
                   "DatabasePassword":{"Ref":"DatabasePassword"},
                   "DatabaseUsername":{"Ref":"DatabaseUsername"},
                   "DatabaseBackupRetentionPeriod":{"Ref":"DatabaseBackupRetentionPeriod"},
                   "DatabaseSubnets":{ "Fn::GetAtt": [ "VPCStack", "Outputs.SubnesPublic" ] } ,
                   "DatabaseSecurityGroups":{"Ref":"DatabaseSecurityGroups"}            
                },
          "TemplateURL": "https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/xxx/rds.json",
          "TimeoutInMinutes": "5"
      },
      "DependsOn": "VPCStack"
    }

  }
```

and i'm returning list from vpc child template and trying to pass into rds template but i get and error saying  Value of property Parameters must be an object with String (or simple type) properties.

i research about it and some say you cannot pass lists into child templates and so on. how can i overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

yes i figured the solution by passing two strings from parent template and join those two string as a list. in this case pass two subnets and create a list of subnetIds

parent template

```
"Subnets1":{
                  "Fn::GetAtt":[
                     "VPCStack",
                     "Outputs.SubnetAPublic"
                  ]
               },
               "Subnets2":{
                  "Fn::GetAtt":[
                     "VPCStack",
                     "Outputs.SubnetBPublic"
                  ]
               }
```

child template

```
"VPCZoneIdentifier": [
           {
            "Ref": "Subnets1"
          },
          {
            "Ref": "Subnets2"
          }
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're talking about the `SubnesPublic` output from the `VPCStack`.

Instead of passing it as is in the `RDSStack`, you can [`Fn::Join`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-join.html?shortFooter=true) the list first. Example:

`"Fn::Join" : [ ":", [ "a", "b", "c" ] ]` will return the string `a:b:c`

and then you can [`Fn::Split`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-split.html?shortFooter=true) it inside the stack. Example:

`"Fn::Split" : [ ":" , "a:b:c" ]` will return the array of string `["a", "b", "c"]`.

So in your case, you can do this:

```
"DatabaseSubnets":{ "Fn::Join" [":", "Fn::GetAtt": [ "VPCStack", "Outputs.SubnesPublic" ]] }
```

and inside the RDSStack, you can read the db subnets as follows:

`"Fn::Split" : [ ":" , {"Ref": "DatabaseSubnets" } ]`

I'm more used to typing in YAML so double-check the json I wrote.